# Concrete5 shared authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication, cookies, shared, concrete5

I have an existing application (Java based on Tomcat 7 using MySQL) and would like to bring up a separate CMS website using Concrete5. I already have thousands of member accounts and an authentication system (session cookie based) in the existing Java application. Both of these applications will exist on the same domain using sub-domains... www.domain.com and application.domain.com.

I'm struggling to find a way to implement this requirement.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Jeff.

Comment: Just to follow up on this... Since Concrete5.7 authentication types have been abstracted out so it should be relatively easy for you to implement your own authentication type to authenticate with external system.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that will work out-of-the-box, but there has been some work done in this area of Concrete5 which should get you part of the way there.

This is a generic "third-party authentication" framework that someone is working on currently:
http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/authentication-testers/

Then there are a few LDAP solutions (I don't really know what LDAP is or how it works -- so it may or may not be useful to your situation):

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/adldap-andamp-c5-integration-for-authentication/#46266

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/packaged-ldap-authentication-working-beta/

(Note that those LDAP links are 1 and 2 years old, respectively, so might need more modifications to work with the latest version of Concrete5).

Finally, note that C5 already includes OpenID authentication -- so if there's some way to easily make your existing system work with OpenID then that could be a possibility as well.

Best of luck!